# Youtube API - getting 500 error php

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, youtube-data-api

I seem to be having a problem with uploading videos or doing anything with the youtube API. It always seems to give me a 500 error on chrome and a blank page on Firefox. This is really troubling me because I have entered everything correctly. my php code is below. Thanks!

```
<?php

// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
set_include_path('google-api-php-client/src');
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
session_start();

/*
* You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
* Google Developers Console <https://console.developers.google.com/>
* For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs,    please see:
* <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
* Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
*/
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'MY ID';


$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'MY KEY';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .     
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
die('The session state did not match.');
}

$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
try{
// REPLACE this value with the path to the file you are uploading.
$videoPath = "/path/to/file.mp4";

// Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
// Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
// This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
// video category.
$snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
$snippet->setTitle("Test title");
$snippet->setDescription("Test description");
$snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));

// Numeric video category. See
// https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list 
$snippet->setCategoryId("22");

// Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
// "private" and "unlisted".
$status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
$status->privacyStatus = "public";

// Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
$video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
$video->setSnippet($snippet);
$video->setStatus($status);

// Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
// reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
// value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
$chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

// Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
// with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
$client->setDefer(true);

// Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
$insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

// Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
$media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
    $client,
    $insertRequest,
    'video/*',
    null,
    true,
    $chunkSizeBytes
);
$media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));


// Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
$status = false;
$handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
  $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
  $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
}

fclose($handle);

// If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
$client->setDefer(false);


$htmlBody .= "<h3>Video Uploaded</h3><ul>";
$htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
    $status['snippet']['title'],
    $status['id']);

$htmlBody .= '</ul>';

 } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
 $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
    htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
 } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
 $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
    htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
 } 

 $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
 } else {
 // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
 $state = mt_rand();
 $client->setState($state);
 $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

 $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
 $htmlBody = <<<END
 <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
 <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before    proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>

<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Video Uploaded</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php =$htmlBody?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload video only with

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
```

You have to use these following things.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl
```

Comment: Sorry, you can. and I am! my code works now. I needed a require once

Comment: where? I have same problem and it seems that is in the Google/Service/YouTube.php file

Comment: Sorry I used composer and need load vendor autoload file